# I installed xampp on Directory E:/xampp , how to access localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed `xampp` on non default directory `E:` and now I am unable to access `phpmyadmin` and my applications in `E:/htdocs` folder. How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `httpd.conf` file located under `conf` folder in
`apache` folder. (`apache/conf/httpd.conf`)

Edit it in Text editor and change the path of root directory.

```
DocumentRoot "d:/newdirectory_name"
...
...
<Directory "d:/newdirectory_name">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
...
```

Comment: Here it is `DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
`

Comment: i am not sure for that but i think first you want to configure your **apache php.ini**
Like

 [XDebug]
;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = **"127.0.0.1"**
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"

Answer (score 0):

****First, You have to install your xampp in the C directory, then you can access your phpmyadmin without any problem****

Comment: Explain the Steps

Comment: **If I tell you a very easy method to fix this,  then that is uninstalled your xampp and again install it. At the installation process at the 3rd step, select your path `C:/xampp`. Then your this problem could be resolved.**